# Maven web project HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I started a`maven-archetype-webapp` web project with the following structure using the `IntellIJ`,

[image]

The `web.xml` file is as following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Bitcoin Wallet</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file is provided below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.puut.bitcoin.controllers">
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**" />
</beans>
```

There is no Java source file in the project so far. I get the error `HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]`.

[image]

I clean and build the project with `Maven` successfully. I upgraded to the `OS Sierra` and there is no `maven` installed in the OS. So, I had to manually configured it. Maven related information is here,

```
$ mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T01:39:06+06:00)
Maven home: /Users/Chaklader/apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"


$ which mvn 

/Users/Chaklader/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn
```

What should I do to run the project?

Update

As mentioned, changed it to

```
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use jsp resolver, you have to define a controller like this:

```
package com.puut.bitcoin.controllers;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class spaController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String pagIndex(Model model){

     return "index";
  }
}
```

In web xml, it's better to explicit declare which configuration file is used by dispatcher servlet.

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't help

Comment: It may help other people no bad idea at all. We all dev application lets be friend :)

Comment: Now, this is correct answer. So, its a Spring project and I get to write controllers to run it as intended.

Comment: The dispatcher servlet forwards request to application controllers. Then, the InternalResourceViewResolver is used to convert the return value of controller's methods into views.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have mapping to URL: `http://<host>/index.jsp`, but you have mapping to URL: `http://<host>/`

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Or you can change `url-pattern` to some other pattern, if you wish.

Comment: Navigate to URL like http://<host>/, where "<host>" is host where your tomcat is running. Or, you can change <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>